# Unable to get Search View items clickable in correct position

Tags: java, android, arrays, searchview, baseadapter

```
private ListView lvProduct;
private ListProductAdapter adapter;
private List<Product> mProductList;
private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;     

adapter = new ListProductAdapter(this, mProductList);

    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position2, long id) {

        }
    });
```

**Here is Search Query Listner **

```
 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    s=s.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<Product> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product listProductAdapter : mProductList){
        String name = listProductAdapter.getSearchName().toLowerCase();
        if(name.contains(s)){
            newList.add(listProductAdapter);
            ;
        }
    }
    adapter.setFilter(newList);
    return true;
}
```

**Here is ListAdapter and  Filter adapter**

```
public ListProductAdapter(Context mContext, List<Product> mProductList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mProductList = mProductList;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mProductList.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mProductList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position2) {
    return mProductList.get(position2).getId();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position2, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_listview, null);
    v.setTag(mProductList.get(position2).getId());
    TextView tvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
    tvName.setText(mProductList.get(position2).getName());
    return v;
}

 public void setFilter(ArrayList<Product> newList){
    mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
    mProductList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I want to get items clicked with **mProductList.get(position2).getId()**
I am getting a sorted new adapter for searchview but i am getting previous adapter position id. But i want a updated listview position id's with updated listview adapter. Please Help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear old list and add new items..
Try this,

```
    public void setFilter(ArrayList<Product> newList){
    mProductList.clear();
    mProductList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: list is stuck with updated list content but it is not returning all the listview elements again. can you please help me on this?

Comment: @AlfredKommina  if query string is empty u will add list object from activity to pass adapter call set filter method

Comment: i didnt get you @GobuCSG Sorry. If setfilter got two elements in search filter then filter is updating mProduct list with two elements(List view populating only two elements after searching). I cant get all the elements after closing search bar.

Comment: @Alfred-kommina 
 
 Do like this, 

 `@Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    s=s.toLowerCase();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){}
    ArrayList<Product> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product listProductAdapter : mProductList){
        String name = listProductAdapter.getSearchName().toLowerCase();
        if(name.contains(s)){
            newList.add(listProductAdapter);
            ;
        }
    }
    adapter.setFilter(newList);
    }else{
    adapter.setFilter(mProductList);
    }
    return true;
}`